# Combine multiple sql / mysql queries in one query

Tags: php, sql, join

I have 5 tables. Namely `user`, `reference_1`, `reference_2`, `reference_3` and `question`

```
user => (user_id,user_name,user_emailid,user_mobno)
reference_1 => (ref_id_1,user_id,ref_name,ref_email,ref_mobno)
reference_2 => (ref_id_2,user_id,ref_name,ref_email,ref_mobno)
reference_3 => (ref_id_3,user_id,ref_name,ref_email,ref_mobno)
question => (que_id,user_id,ref_id_1,ref_id_2,ref_id_3,que1_name,que2_name,que3_name,que4_name,que5_name,que6a_name,que6b_name,que7_name,qa1,qa2,qa3,qa4,qa5,qa6a,qa6b,qa7,flag)
```

I fired 4 consecutive queries:

Query 1: Fetching the data from the `user` table and `question` using a LEFT JOIN

```
select u.user_name,u.user_emailid,u.user_mobno,
  q.que1_name,q.qa1,q.que2_name,q.qa2,q.que3_name,q.qa3,q.que4_name,q.qa4,q.que5_name,q.qa5,q.que6a_name,q.qa6a,q.que6b_name,q.qa6b,q.que7_name,q.qa7
from user u
LEFT JOIN question q
on u.user_id = q.user_id
WHERE q.flag = 1
```

Query 2: Fetching the data from the `user` table and `reference_1` using LEFT JOIN

```
select r1.ref_name,r1.ref_email,r1.ref_mobno,
  q.que1_name,q.qa1,q.que2_name,q.qa2,q.que3_name,q.qa3,q.que4_name,q.qa4,q.que5_name,q.qa5,q.que6a_name,q.qa6a,q.que6b_name,q.qa6b,q.que7_name,q.qa7
from reference_1 r1
left join question q
on r1.ref_id_1 = q.ref_id_1
```

Query 3: Fetching the data from the `user` table and `reference_2` using LEFT JOIN

```
select r2.ref_name,r2.ref_email,r2.ref_mobno,  
  q.que1_name,q.qa1,q.que2_name,q.qa2,q.que3_name,q.qa3,q.que4_name,q.qa4,q.que5_name,q.qa5,q.que6a_nam e,q.qa6a,q.que6b_name,q.qa6b,q.que7_name,q.qa7
from reference_2 r2
left join question q
on r2.ref_id_2 = q.ref_id_2
```

Query 4: Fetching the data from the `user` table and `reference_3` using LEFT JOIN

```
select r3.ref_name,r3.ref_email,r3.ref_mobno,  
  q.que1_name,q.qa1,q.que2_name,q.qa2,q.que3_name,q.qa3,q.que4_name,q.qa4,q.que5_name,q.qa5,q.que6a_name,q.qa6a,q.que6b_name,q.qa6b,q.que7_name,q.qa7
from reference_3 r3
left join question q
on r3.ref_id_3 = q.ref_id_3
```

Now there is a requirement to combine all 4 queries in one to show the data.

I tried JOIN all these queries in one query

```
select u.user_name,u.user_emailid,u.user_mobno,

q.que1_name,q.qa1,q.que2_name,q.qa2,q.que3_name,q.qa3,q.que4_name,q.qa4,q.que5_name,q.qa5,q.que6a_name,q.qa6a,q.que6b_name,q.qa6b,q.que7_name,q.qa7,

r1.ref_name,r1.ref_email,r1.ref_mobno,  q.que1_name,q.qa1,q.que2_name,q.qa2,q.que3_name,q.qa3,q.que4_name,q.qa4,q.que5_name,q.qa5,q.que6a_name,q.qa6a,q.que6b_name,q.qa6b,q.que7_name,q.qa7,

r2.ref_name,r2.ref_email,r2.ref_mobno,  q.que1_name,q.qa1,q.que2_name,q.qa2,q.que3_name,q.qa3,q.que4_name,q.qa4,q.que5_name,q.qa5,q.que6a_name,q.qa6a,q.que6b_name,q.qa6b,q.que7_name,q.qa7,

r3.ref_name,r3.ref_email,r3.ref_mobno, q.que1_name,q.qa1,q.que2_name,q.qa2,q.que3_name,q.qa3,q.que4_name,q.qa4,q.que5_name,q.qa5,q.que6a_name,q.qa6a,q.que6b_name,q.qa6b,q.que7_name,q.qa7

from user u
LEFT JOIN question q
on u.user_id = q.user_id
WHERE q.flag = 1
LEFT JOIN reference_1 r1
LEFT JOIN question q1
on r1.ref_id_1 = q1.ref_id_1
LEFT JOIN reference_2 r2
LEFT JOIN question q2
on r2.ref_id_2 = q2.ref_id_2
LEFT JOIN reference_3 r3
LEFT JOIN question q3
on r3.ref_id_3 = q3.ref_id_3
```

But this query is not working.

Comment: one issue is obvious `WHERE q.flag = 1` and should be at the end.

Comment: actually this is the solve :) you should post it as an answer ;)

Comment: Abhik Chakraborty no its not working. I m getting #1064 error in your sql syntax

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: Hmm i see duplicate selects this is not allowed. You have selected `q.que1_name,q.qa1,q.que2_name` first and then again in the 3rd,4th and 5th line you added them again. Remove the duplicate selects.

Comment: duplicate selected columns won't throw a sql syntax error, obviously these should be removed but it won't cause the SQL not to run. The WHERE clause should be after the FROM clause and all of the JOIN statements.

Answer (score 1):

Because you screwed syntax order...

Multi join works like this:

```
select u.user_name,u.user_emailid,u.user_mobno,     q.que1_name,q.qa1,q.que2_name,q.qa2,q.que3_name,q.qa3,q.que4_name,q.qa4,q.que5_name,q.qa5,q.    que6a_name,q.qa6a,q.que6b_name,q.qa6b,q.que7_name,q.qa7,

r1.ref_name,r1.ref_email,r1.ref_mobno,   q.que1_name,q.qa1,q.que2_name,q.qa2,q.que3_name,q.qa3,q.que4_name,q.qa4,q.que5_name,q.qa5,q.    que6a_name,q.qa6a,q.que6b_name,q.qa6b,q.que7_name,q.qa7,

r2.ref_name,r2.ref_email,r2.ref_mobno,  q.que1_name,q.qa1,q.que2_name,q.qa2,q.que3_name,q.qa3,q.que4_name,q.qa4,q.que5_name,q.qa5,q.    que6a_name,q.qa6a,q.que6b_name,q.qa6b,q.que7_name,q.qa7,

r3.ref_name,r3.ref_email,r3.ref_mobno, q.que1_name,q.qa1,q.que2_name,q.qa2,q.que3_name,q.qa3,q.que4_name,q.qa4,q.que5_name,q.qa5,q.    que6a_name,q.qa6a,q.que6b_name,q.qa6b,q.que7_name,q.qa7

from question q
LEFT JOIN user u USING(user_id)
LEFT JOIN reference_1 r1 USING(ref_id_1)
LEFT JOIN reference_2 r2 USING(ref_id_2)
LEFT JOIN reference_3 r3 USING(ref_id_3)
WHERE q.flag = 1
```

Where must be at the end...
Joins must be stated completely and cannot be mixed. Order in dependency works you can have sub and subsub and so on dependencies without a problem.

One thing you did pretty good: You set-up same name for foreign key in both JOIN tables.
In this case you can simply replace r1.t1 = r2.t2 stuff and just define the join table in function USING(t1). :)

Comment: Steini I m unable any of the ref_name, ref_email, ref_mobno using this query

Comment: Steini I m unable to fetch reference_1, reference_2 and reference_3 records using the query and thanks for guiding me to use function USING()

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. Uses nested join to the reference tables onto the question table.

```
   SELECT u.user_name
    ,u.user_emailid
    ,u.user_mobno
    ,q.que1_name
    ,q.qa1
    ,q.que2_name
    ,q.qa2
    ,q.que3_name
    ,q.qa3
    ,q.que4_name
    ,q.qa4
    ,q.que5_name
    ,q.qa5
    ,q.que6a_name
    ,q.qa6a
    ,q.que6b_name
    ,q.qa6b
    ,q.que7_name
    ,q.qa7
    ,r1.ref_name
    ,r1.ref_email
    ,r1.ref_mobno
    ,r2.ref_name
    ,r2.ref_email
    ,r2.ref_mobno
    ,q.que1_name
    ,r3.ref_name
    ,r3.ref_email
    ,r3.ref_mobno
FROM dbo.user u
LEFT JOIN question q
LEFT JOIN reference_1 r1 ON r1.ref_id_1 = q.ref_id_1
LEFT JOIN reference_2 r2 ON r2.ref_id_2 = q.ref_id_2
LEFT JOIN reference_3 r3 ON r3.ref_id_3 = q.ref_id_3 ON u.user_id = q.user_id
WHERE q.flag = 1
```